# Hide tables and figures and keep text and vice versa?

Tags: tables, comments

Is there an easy way to hide all text and only keep tables and figures and vice versa? My figures and tables are referenced with `\ref` and embedded with `\input`.

Comment: So, basically, all input lines *except* those that start with `\input` should be ignored? Do you input anything with `\input` (sorry, couldn't resist the pun...) other than `figure` and `table` environments?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the space ocuppied by text, using your `tables and figures' version?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I also add chapters (from main) and sections (from chapters) with input. You made me realise how I can do it. I can grep anything in the sections, which is not a line of text and compile those modified tex files. Not a super easy solution, but doable.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Either way works fine. I guess I could somehow use a white font? Preferably I want to remove the space if possible.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you. It sets up two user macros, called `\HideAllFigsAndTabs` and `\ShowOnlyFigsAndTabs`. It goes (hopefully) without saying that at most one of the two LaTeX macros should be executed in a document.

The LaTeX macros' sole job is to assign one or the other of the Lua functions `hide_all_figs_and_tabs` and `show_only_figs_and_tabs` to the `process_input_buffer` callback. Once assigned to this callback, the active Lua function acts like a pre-processor on the input stream, before (La)TeX normal processing even begins.

The only restriction on input is that only one of four instructions `\begin{figure}`, `\end{figure}`, `\begin{table}`, and `\end{table}` is allowed to occur in any given line. Hopefully, that's not a binding restriction on your coding habits.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% create two "dummy" tex files
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Hello World}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mytab.tex}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Goodbye World}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
in_fig_or_tab = false

function hide_all_figs_and_tabs ( s )
  if   s:find ( "\\begin{figure" ) 
    or s:find ( "\\begin{table"  ) then
         in_fig_or_tab = true
         return ""
  elseif s:find ( "\\end{figure" ) 
      or s:find ( "\\end{table"  ) then 
         in_fig_or_tab = false
         return ""
  elseif in_fig_or_tab == true then
         return ""
  end
  return s
end

function show_only_figs_and_tabs ( s )
  if   s:find ( "\\begin{figure" ) 
    or s:find ( "\\begin{table"  ) then
         in_fig_or_tab = true
         return s
  elseif s:find ( "\\end{figure" ) 
      or s:find ( "\\end{table"  ) then 
         in_fig_or_tab = false
         return s
  -- Must also enable all lines that contain '\input'
  -- statements or an '\end{document}' directive:
  elseif s:find ( "\\input" ) 
      or s:find ( "\\end{document}" ) 
      or in_fig_or_tab == true then
         return s
  end
  -- If none of the above is true, return empty string:
  return "" 
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}   
%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\HideAllFigsAndTabs{\directlua{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
    hide_all_figs_and_tabs, "hide_all_figs_and_tabs" )}}
\newcommand\ShowOnlyFigsAndTabs{\directlua{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
    show_only_figs_and_tabs, "show_only_figs_and_tabs" )}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

%% Execute *only one* of the following two instructions:
%\HideAllFigsAndTabs
\ShowOnlyFigsAndTabs

\lipsum[1]

\input myfig

\lipsum[2]

\input mytab

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```